# HTML form is not redirecting

Tags: html

I've written probably a dozen forms for this project but for some reason this ONE is not working. I can't discern any difference between it and any of my other forms.

By not working, I mean the page does not redirect when the submit button is clicked.

Also, the default value I try to put in the 'patient' field isn't appearing but that's not important.

It's probably something really silly like an unbalanced tag or something but I just cannot find it. Can a pair of fresh eyes help me out?

```
<form id='addBill' method='POST' action="/add_to_bill.php">
<table class='t' style='width:100%'>
<tr>
    <td class='tt'><p>Patient ID</p></td>
    <td class='tt'><input disabled class='t' type="numeric" name="patient" value=<?php getP('id') ?>></td>
    <td class='tt'><p>Visit ID</p></td>
    <td class='tt'><input class='t' type="numeric" name="visit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='tt'><p>Invoice Number</p></td>
    <td class='tt'><input class='t' type="numeric" name="invoice"></td>
    <td class='tt'><p class='t'>Due Date: (format: e.g. <?php echo "'".date('Y-m-d')."'"; ?>)</p></td>
    <td class='tt'><input class='t' type="text" name="date" value=<?php echo "'".date('Y-m-d')."'"?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='tt'><input class='t' type="submit" value="Go"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: where's the php for this? nothing you posted (even the image of code) support the question/problem/php tag.

Comment: `type="numeric"` that isn't a valid type https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: I added the php tag because php is part of the stack and embedded in some parts of the form, and maybe somehow that's causing the issue? Although I use it similarly in other forms and it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I've corrected 'numeric' to 'number'. The form still does not redirect though.

Comment: sorry but I can't help you with what you posted. I don't see anything related to "redirection". Wait for someone else or post your php. I have a feeling why but I can't know that till I know exactly what I'm dealing with here.

Comment: ok you've an answer below, see that. I'm out.

Comment: you should have posted real code instead of "an image of it". You should read the following post as to why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question then maybe, maybe you'll understand. I voted to close as unclear btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the image of the code i noticed there is a form tag without the closed form tag. there are two form tag in it, one without closed form tag which is at most top of the code and another one is at bottom

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid like this. Thanks! I'll accept when the site brings me off cooldown.

Comment: try seperate it and dont mixed up the form tag. i mean try use one form tag instead of putting two form tag in one page. try to clean up the code. looks abit messy there.